# LINQ to Entity Framework - multiple include paths result in lousy TSQL

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Given the following LINQ to Entities (EF4) query...

```
var documents =
    from doc in context.Documents
        .Include(d => d.Batch.FinancialPeriod)
        .Include(d => d.Batch.Contractor)
        .Include(d => d.GroupTypeHistory.Select(gth => gth.GroupType))
        .Include(d => d.Items.Select(i => i.Versions))
        .Include(d => d.Items.Select(i => i.Versions.Select(v => v.ProductPackPeriodic.ProductPack.Product.HomeDelivery)))
        .Include(d => d.Items.Select(i => i.Versions.Select(v => v.ProductPackPeriodic.ProductPack.Product.Manufacturer)))
        .Include(d => d.Items.Select(i => i.Versions.Select(v => v.ProductPackPeriodic.ProductPeriodic)))
        .Include(d => d.Items.Select(i => i.Versions.Select(v => v.ProductPackPeriodic.SpecialContainerIndicator)))
        .Include(d => d.Items.Select(i => i.Versions.Select(v => v.Endorsements.Select(e => e.Periodic))))
        where doc.ID == this.documentID
        select doc;

Document document = documents.FirstOrDefault();
```

Where ...

- a Document will always have a Batch which in turn will always have a
  financial period and a contractor
- a Document will always have one or
  more GroupTypeHistory, each of which will always have a GroupType
- a Document will have zero or more Item's, which in turn will have one
  or more Version's
- a Version will have zero or one ProductPackPeriodic
- a ProductPackPeriodic will always have one ProductPack and one
  ProductPeriodic, along with zero or one SpecialContainerIndicator
- a ProductPack will always have one Product
- a Product will have zero or one Manufacturer, and zero or one HomeDelivery
- a Version will have zero or more Endorsements, each of which will have one Periodic

The above LINQ query generates some of the worst TSQL that I have ever seen, with some of the related tables included multiple times (probably because they are referenced within the query multiple times) and takes significantly longer than I would like to run (the tables concerned can contain millions of rows, but this is not the cause).

I know that there has to be a better way to write it (taking into account all of the different reference types that I describe above) which will result in better TSQL, but every version that I try fails to return the data correctly.

Can anybody assist in pointing me to a better solution?

If it makes it any easier to understand, were I writing TSQL directly I would be looking at something like the following...

```
select *
from Document d
    inner join Batch b 
        inner join FinancialPeriod fp on b.FinancialPeriodID = fp.FinancialPeriodID
        inner join Contractor c on b.ContractorID = c.ContractorID
    on d.BatchID = b.BatchID
    inner join DocumentGroupType dgt on d.DocumentID = dgt.DocumentID
    left join Item i
        left join ItemVersion iv
            left join ProductPackPeriodic ppp
                inner join ProductPack pack 
                    inner join Product p 
                        left join Manufacturer m on p.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
                        left join HomeDeliveryProduct hdp on p.ProductID = hdp.ProductID
                    on pack.ProductID = p.ProductID
                on ppp.ProductPackID = pack.ProductPackID
                inner join ProductPeriodic pp on ppp.ProductPeriodicID = pp.ProductPeriodicID
                left join SpecialContainerIndicator sci on ppp.SpecialContainerIndicatorCode = sci.SpecialContainerIndicatorCode
            on iv.ProductPackPeriodicID = ppp.ProductPackPeriodicID
            left join ItemVersionEndorsement ive 
                inner join EndorsementPeriodic ep on ive.EndorsementPeriodicID = ep.EndorsementPeriodicID
            on iv.ItemVersionID = ive.ItemVersionID
        on i.ItemID = iv.ItemID
    on d.DocumentID = i.DocumentID
where d.DocumentID = 33 -- example value
```

This may also make the relationship requirements clearer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For scenarios like this i write specific stored procedures and then use EFExtensions with a custom materializer to not only get excellent performance but also correctly materialized entities.

Comment: Excellent answer; this has significantly improved performance as I hoped and (as you suggested) allows me to specify my own TSQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any good answer for EF, but it might suit you to use a micro ORM for certain complex queries. Micro ORMs are essentially low-level wrappers over SQL, that allow you to get strongly typed objects, along with other convenience features. You can take a look at [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), for example, which is used by this very site for some of the bottleneck queries. It should perform very close to native SQL performance.